# Internal error not handled System.InvalidOperationException at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError

Tags: oracle, transactionscope

I have a web application and I am getting an error related to oracle.

> System.InvalidOperationException Internal error not handled (-2)
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError()

This is the scenario.

sql1

```
select * from table1@otheroracledb
```

sql2

```
select * from table2
```

I am getting this error when I run the sql1 and then sql2.

What could be the problem?